# Is there any way to find out any quests are available in the surrounding area?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Yesterday I was walking with the world map open and I almost missed a quest giver. Now I am afraid I may have missed others, as I was doing the same thing most of my time in the Lakeshire Mountains.

I also took a different path to the target location, where I discovered another quest giver. I was wondering if there is any feature to find quests available within some range of your current location?

I know I can always find them by watching for the exclamation point in the minimap, and yet I was about to miss couple quests if I hadn't watched it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is when you start up, is to complete all the quests that the quest giver gave you. Doing so will usually ,after you completed most of the quests from him, make him give you a quest to go to another area with quest givers.

Also, it is a good idea to do all the quests from a quest giver as the quest rewards increase as you complete the quest chain.

Other than this follow the next quest giver thing, you can't pretty much do anything else but google the area you're in and see what quest givers are in there for A/H.

And other than that, the only thing left to do is to use a [quest giver add-on](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/everyquest-questgivers)(which should be the answer you were looking for). These are great as they show on your minimap AND map all the quest givers. You might find one similar to what I linked you to which you might find useful.

Also, maybe some quest givers won't be shown on map as you don't meet the level requirements for that quest. So if you pass by an NPC at lvl 10 he won't have any quests for you, but if you go again at lvl 15 he might have. Just a thing to keep in mind.

Ok, so I hope this helps.

P.S.:[Quests and Leveling Add-ons](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/category/quests-leveling)

Answer (score 1):

[Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/) is an obvious option for filtering quests by zone and faction (i.e. Horde or Alliance) and checking which you may not have done.  When navigating by zone, Wowhead will show all quest givers for that zone on a map to help you as well.  Use the "Show on Map..." button, then your faction of choice followed by "Quest givers".

[EveryQuest](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/everyquest) performs a similar function in game.  It can query the WoW servers to find out which quests you have already completed, and then lets you filter to [only show uncompleted quests as well as organizing them by zone](http://media-curse.cursecdn.com/attachments/14/986/0aa11a42c3b6807aabfdd97b7768a781.jpg).  You will then have to look up the quest via other means to find out where to pick it up though.